# How to find if there are active downloads using API level 8?

Tags: android

Is there a way to find if there is active downloads programmatically working on API level 8?
I need to do an application for android that turns off wifi if there a no downloads active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find if there is active downloads programmatically working on API level 8?

No, sorry. The closest thing that you can do is monitor `TrafficStats` and see if there is any Internet traffic at all. Whether those represent "downloads" is up to the app using the Internet.